# Pause VBA macro, allow user to make a selection, and restart where it left off

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to allow the user to make a selection, run some code, pause for another selection, run more code?

I work with documents with large number of tables that eventually convert to HTML. Sometimes the formatting on two like tables doesn't convert the same. Knowing how the converter works, I'd like to copy all of the formatting data from one table and "paste" it onto another one.

I've the idea of a userform to have the user select something, hit a copy button, select something else and hit a paste button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer function allows you to do this. It may not be the best way to code, but it is the answer to your problem:

```
'1st code here
Start = Timer
Do While Timer < Start + 10
  DoEvents
Loop
'do 2nd code here
```

`DoEvents` allows the user to select text, etc. After 10 seconds, the code resumes at "2nd code."

Comment: So DoEvents breaks out of a macro? It would be simple enough to create a way that isn't based on a timer to determine a stop point for DoEvents.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer because it answers the question simply and directly; however, if you happen to stop by again and have a way to allow a user to work on a document while a userform is displayed, I'd be glad to hear it :)

Comment: DoEvents "yields to other processes," including user input (per the [help file](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV806084859990&lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=fb08066b%2D2e3b%2D438b%2D9123%2D6e6caca10a55) for the TIMER function). To keep a userform displayed, try setting modal in the `UserForm.Show` method to 0. The details on what this does are [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV806086089990&lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=1225bda6%2D7fb3%2D495a%2Daa33%2D91852e2446ac).

Answer (score 1):

You can use global a global variable:

```
Public myVar as Variant

Sub fillmyVar()
    myVar = Selection
End Sub

Sub doSth()
    ' use myVar and the new selected text
End Sub
```

Comment: I considered this but I wanted to avoid global variables. It's a personal coding choice 8-P

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from Aaron and incorporating it with a ToggleButton in the Userform you can successfully pause the code. With this you can then work in an additional selection to change the operation.

I originally did not use Global or Public Variables but soon learnt that its easier for passing data between `Subs` and `Userforms`

Userform:

```
Public Sub ToggleButton1_AfterUpdate()


    'Program is Paused / Selected to Pause

    If ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        'Changing the Text of the Toggle button once the program is selected to Pause
        'If program paused then button will display continue
        ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Caption = "Continue"


        'For Sending to  Loop Code
        ProgramStatus = "0"
        Call LoopCode.PrgStat(ProgramStatus)

    End If



    'Program is running / Selected to run

    If ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
        'Changing the Text of the Toggle button once the program is selected to continue
        'If program running then button will display pause
        ProgBar.ToggleButton1.Caption = "Pause"

        'For Sending to  Loop Code
        ProgramStatus = "1"
        Call LoopCode.PrgStat(ProgramStatus)

    End If


End Sub
```

In your Module

```
Public Status As String

Public Sub PrgStat(ByVal ProgStatus As String)

   Status = ProgStatus

End Sub




Sub SomeSub()

 Do While

   ' Some Loop Code Running




          If Status = "1" Then

          'Toggle Not Pressed           

          End If

          If Status = "0" Then

             'Toggle Button Pressed

             Do While Status = "0"
                'Program will stop here until the togglebutton on the 
                'userform is pressed again which changes Status = 1

                'This is where you can make another selection on the 
                'userform

                 DoEvents

             Loop


          End If

   Loop
 End Sub
```