# Pause VBA Word macro, allow user to make a selection, and restart where it left off

Tags: vba

I have a requirement for VBA script in Microsoft Word to pause so that the user can select text that will be copied to the clipboard so that it can exported to an Excel file.  The user will make a number of selections and finally indicate he/she is done when the contents of the clipboard will be copied to a template Excel file.

I have the code working to copy each selection to the clipboard and then all rows to the Excel file.  But I need assistence in figuring out how to pause the code to allow the user to make the selection and then restart the code to copy the selection to the clipboard.  I am able to get the userform with toggle switch to switch states and labels when pressed.  But have not figured out how to pause the VBA code to allow the user to navigate to the next section of the Word document for the next selection.

The Stakeoverflow question/answer below appears to address this requirement but I have not been able to get it to work.  It appears that the code is incomplete.

[Pause VBA macro, allow user to make a selection, and restart where it left off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872068/pause-vba-macro-allow-user-to-make-a-selection-and-restart-where-it-left-off)

Can someone provide example VBA code that accomplishes this?

Your assistence is much appreciated as I have been beating my head against the wall and it is starting to hurt!

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Code execution would "stop" where-ever you put an `InputBox`.  Please show the section of code where you are having trouble. See **how to create a [mcve]**.

Comment: Don't pause ... use a modeless form to capture selections, and when the user exits the modeless form, return to the main form. But, as @ashleedawg notes - are best able to help when you have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way in VBA to "pause" a macro. Code must run to completion... Unless there's a command for user input.

Input can be requested via the `InputBox` and `MsgBox` methods, but those block access to the document because they're *modal*. A **UserForm**, however, can be set to display as *non-modal*, meaning it stays on top, but doesn't block access to the document or the application features. Since you're already working with a UserForm, this can be implemented relatively easily.

In the small example below, the `Continue` button runs the code to perform an action on the user selection. When `Done` is clicked the entire code is exited and the form unloaded.

[image]

**Code behind the user form**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
    Debug.Print Selection.Range.Text
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    'Position the form near the top-left of the window
    'So that the user can work with the document
    Me.Top = Application.ActiveWindow.Top + 50
    Me.Left = Application.ActiveWindow.Left + 50
End Sub
```

**Code in a regular module**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DisplayModeless()
    Dim frm As frmModelessForInput

    Set frm = New frmModelessForInput
    frm.Show False  'Display as non-modal
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example code.  I am calling the frmModelessForInput form from another form.  I was able to get it to work once I set both forms' "ShowModal" behavior to False.  However, when I execute "Call DisplayModeless" from the calling form the code in the calling form continues to execute.  The behavior I need is that program control goes to frmModelessForInput form until "Done" is pressed.  This form will call a subroutine to copy the selected text to a "clipboard" string which will be passed back to calling form which will then copy it to the Excel file.

Comment: @KaiserOtto: On Stack Overflow, the better/preferred thing to do would be leave this question as "answered"  - it could, indeed, help others with a similar question, but not your level of detail - and start a NEW question. Changing a question is fine as long as there are no Answers that base on the original question. As soon as there is an answer that does address the original question, better to start a new one - which can contain a link to the previous discussion, if it's relevant. You can "rollback" your edits (after copying, I'd imagine) to the original question quite easily :-)

Comment: Cindy, thanks for your coaching.  I have rolled back the Question to the initial question and created a new question per your suggestion.